# Python/Pandas: Add a field with current timestamp (epoch/unix)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a below pandas dataframe

```
id    city     country
1    chicago   USA
2    houston   USA
3    toronto   CAN
```

I want to add an additional column record_creation_time with current system timestamp (in epoch/unix) like below

```
id    city     country   record_creation_time
1    chicago   USA         1605897987
2    houston   USA         1605897987
3    toronto   CAN         1605897987
```

How can I achieve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get the value by doing:

```
import pandas as pd
now = pd.Timestamp.today().timestamp()
```

and assign it like

```
df = df.assign(record_creation_time=now)
```

Comment: does this automatically truncate the value?

Answer (score 1):

Is this something similar to what you want?

```py
import time, pandas as pd

d = {'a': [1,2,3], 'b':['one','two','three']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['c'] = int(time.time())
```

result:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52jzs.png)